# Alamofire library Void is not convertible to Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a function which sets the JSON results into an NSDictionary. It then uses this value to call a few other functions. I am using Alamofire and since I wrote this app in Swift 1, some this has changed which is giving me errors.

Here is the function:

```
func fetchApiData() {


    // I believe this is the problem code below.


            let _requestURL1 = Alamofire.request(.GET,dataSourceURL!)
    _requestURL1.responseJSON { (_requestUrl, _requestResponse, _objJSON1, error) -> Void in
        if(_objJSON1 != nil)
        {
            let jsonResult1 = _objJSON1 as NSDictionary;
            self.checkIP(jsonResult1)
            self.checkGeo(jsonResult1)
        }
        else{
            return
        }
    }
        let _requestURL2 = Alamofire.request(.GET,self.dataSourceURL2!)
        _requestURL2.responseJSON { (_requestUrl, _requestResponse, _objJSON2, error) -> Void in
            if(_objJSON2 != nil)
            {
                let jsonResult2 = _objJSON2 as NSDictionary;
                self.checkDNS(jsonResult2)
                NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.refreshFrequencyInt, target: self, selector: Selector("fetchApiData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
            else{
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Apparently now, this line:

```
    _requestURL1.responseJSON { (_requestUrl, _requestResponse, _objJSON1, error) -> Void in
```

gives me this error:

```
'(_, _, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void'
```

I have tried the solutions for this issue but I can't seem to get the code working in the same way it was before.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        (JSON) -> Void in
            let JSONDictonary = JSON.result.value as! NSDictionary
           let photoInfos = (JSONDictonary.valueForKey("photos") as! [NSDictionary]).filter({
                ($0["nsfw"] as! Bool) == false
            }).map{
                PhotoInfo(id: $0["id"] as! Int, url: $0["image_url"] as! String)
            }
```